# Scaling multi-channel pub/sub via web-sockets

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine, em-websocket

I have been looking into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/957367) which provides a minimal functional implementation of channelled pub/sub style communication over websockets.

For multiple channels we can have a local hash of `EM::Channel` instances which can be created on the fly as per requirements. What I am concerned with is how can this setup be scaled to support a cluster of server instances or what alternatives are available to facilitate channeled pub/sub via web-sockets which are usable in clustered deployments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jet](http://jetbus.io) Protocol provides strict pub/sub (no-poll) semantics and is open source. It is far more powerful than subscribing to "Channels" (It is called "Fetching" in the Jet wording.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As I have myself found since asking the question a year back, distributed event bus extending to the browser is the way to go. This concept is not unique to the jet protocol, and since I originally tagged the post with ruby, I take this opportunity to point out some other interesting solutions -- vert.x and STOMP on torquebox stack which supports jruby out of the box.